# VBA Access Object Type Returned For Combobox Field

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I iterate a record set that returns a field of type `field2`?
Is there a way to tell how many objects are in the `field2` type?

Let me describe the relevant aspects of my table:

[image]

The table `fields` has `field NMR` which contains a list of possible options a user can select in another table.  In the `Experiments` table, the field NMR is a combobox with populates the options from the other table.

[image]

The way I do this is in the `Experiments` table design, I have set the field this way:

[image]

Now in one of my forms, I need to read the value in `Experiments!NMR` which can be a multiple selections allowed combobox.  The recordset rs!NMR is of type `Field2`.

To get the values, you iterate using an integer (i.e. `rs!NMR(0)` would return the first selected option).  The problem is I don't know how to get the field count and calling `!NMR(i)` where i is greater than the number of elements will invoke a `Run time error '3265', Object doesn't exist in this collection`.

Their exist a `size` method only returns the field width size (4?) and the documentation states this is the size of the data type within the `field2` object.

There doesn't seem to be a `count` method associated with `field2` as using `!NMR.Count` invokes `runtime error 438, Object doesn't support this method`.

Code:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim qry As String

qry = "SELECT * FROM Experiments"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenSnapshot)

With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 to !NMR.Count ' or SOMETHING - this is the problem
            ' this is irrelevant, I need to know how to iterate the list               
        Next i
        .MoveNext
    Loop

End With

rs.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

I've also tried logic control such as

`Do While(!NMR(i) <> vbNullString)` since the individual components are strings, but no luck.  This issues the same `3265: Item isn't found` error.  Same for a loop with this check `Do While Not IsNull(!NMR(i))`

Is there a way to tell how many objects are in the Field !NMR?

Comment: http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/navigating-recordsets-with-multi-value-lookup-fields.html this shows you how to do this. It was pretty easy to find actually.

Comment: Over react much? Your def reading into it too much lol

Comment: @DougCoats Myb then.  I googled for a while- I thought you were saying I didn't attempt to find it on my own first.

Comment: You know what they about making assumptions right? <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the complex [Field2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194326.aspx) to a `Recordset2` object and loop through it.

```
Sub Whatever()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsComplex As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim qry As String

    qry = "SELECT * FROM Experiments"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenSnapshot)

    Do While Not rs.EOF

        Set rsComplex = rs("NMR").Value
            rsComplex.MoveLast
            rsComplex.MoveFirst

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To rsComplex.RecordCount - 1 ' Asker modified
            Debug.Print rsComplex(0)
            rsComplex.MoveNext
        Next i

        rsComplex.Close
        Set rsComplex = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @Chemistpp Thanks, I overlooked that. I always loop recordsets from 1 to avoid  .RecordCount -1.

Comment: I also overlooked it.  The MS VBA debugger didn't for us.